# Define when to flush log entries to database in Enterprise Library 4.1

Tags: enterprise-library, logging-application-block

I'm trying to create a custom database trace listener based on the FormattedDatabaseTraceListenerData and I'm having some doubts regarding its performance. What's the best way to cache in-memory logging entries so less transactions/connections to write logging data are made?

I'm using Enterprise Library 4.1.
I think I have seen this type of caching options somewhere but I lost track of it.

Trace Listener [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.logging.database.configuration.formatteddatabasetracelistenerdata.aspx)